# Handling empty strings in string detection

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to use str_detect and not convert "" to another string pattern.  Is there an easy way to deal with empty string patterns "" which right now generates a warning.  I would like this to produce TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE

```
library( tidyverse )
str_detect('matt', c( "matt","joe","liz","", NA))
```

Comment: just do it in the other way around `str_detect(c( "matt","joe","liz","", NA), 'matt')` if you really want the last element from output to be `FALSE` instead of `NA`, your input should be `c( "matt","joe","liz","", "NA")` , note `NA` inside `"``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
str_detect(replace_na(v1, ''), 'matt')
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

If the match is not for a substring, then `%in%` would be useful

```
v1 %in% 'matt'
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c( "matt","joe","liz","", NA)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're not tied to `str_detect()` perhaps try `grepl()`?

```
grepl("matt", c( "matt","joe","liz","", NA))

#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I prefer this one because it handles NAs better (str_detect won't return any rows that contain NAs)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with package `stringi` the base of package `stringr`.

```
x <- c( "matt","joe","liz","", NA)
stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, 'matt') & !is.na(x)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The `NA` value must be tested, if not `stri_detect_*` will return `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do-

```
v1 <- c( "matt","joe","liz","", NA)
sapply(v1, identical, "matt")
```

Output-

```
 matt   joe   liz        <NA> 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```